# Accessing the object data inside an array which is inside the main array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Here is my JSON DATA -

```
    allsurvey[
{eachquestion:
        [{question:sdvsd,
        answeroptions:[fsdf,sdf],
        questiontype:multiChoice},

        {question:sdf,
        answeroptions:sdf,
        questiontype:textbox}],
    noofques:2,
    surveytitle:aaaa
    }
]
```

I want to access the values inside the array "eachquestion" i.e,  question, answeroptions

Comment: `{allsurvey[` This is invalid

Comment: `{allsurvey : [` This will make it valid. And what holds this entire object?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav No it is still invalid, `{allsurvey: [` should make it ok

Comment: may be you are right, I am a bit new to jquery and JSON

Comment: {"eachquestion":["{\"question\":\"sdvsd\",\"answeroptions\":[\"fsdf\",\"sdf\"],\"questiontype\":\"multiChoice\"}","{\"question\":\"sdf\",\"answeroptions\":\"sdf\",\"questiontype\":\"textbox\"}"],"noofques":2,"surveytitle":"aaaa"}

Comment: this is the data I am getting in console with console.log(JSON.stringify(allsurvey[id]));

Comment: does it make any sense

Comment: @HimanshuYadav do `console.log(allsurvey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible data structure could be this. I add an example with access to the items:

```js
var object = {
    allsurvey: [{
        eachquestion: [{
            question: 'sdvsd',
            answeroptions: ['fsdf', 'sdf'],
            questiontype: 'multiChoice'
        }, {
            question: 'sdf',
            answeroptions: 'sdf',
            questiontype: 'textbox'
        }],
        noofques: 2,
        surveytitle: 'aaaa'
    }]
};


object.allsurvey.forEach(function (a) {
    a.eachquestion.forEach(function (b) {
        document.write(Object.keys(b).map(function (k) {
            return k + ': ' + b[k];
        }).join('<br>'));
        document.write('<hr>');
    });
});
```